# Retrieving data from web

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
driver_BV= webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver_BV.get("https://www.qvc.com/handbags-and-luggage/handbags/clutches/_/N-1cknw/c.html?qq=mh")
product_BV=[]
price_BV=[]
elementHTML=driver_BV.find_element("class name", 'productInfoWrapper')
Final=[]
children_element=elementHTML.find_elements("class name", 'plContent')

print('''
      a. Retrieve data
      b. Create the graph
      c. Display the matrix
      d. Save to Excel file
      e. Exit
      ''')

while True:
    select_option_BV = input("Select option:")
    if select_option_BV == 'a':
        for child_element in children_element:
            title=child_element.find_element("class name", 'productDesc').get_attribute('innerText')
            product_BV.append(title)
            titlu=child_element.find_element("class name", 'priceSell')
            price=titlu.get_attribute('innerText')
            price_BV.append(price)
            print ('Products:', product_BV)
            print ('Prices:', price_BV)
            price=price.replace("$","")
            Final.append(float(price))
            Product_title_series=pd.Series(product_BV)
            Product_price_series=pd.Series(Final)
            product_rows={"Product name":Product_title_series, "Price":Product_price_series}
            Product_Matrix_Framework=pd.DataFrame(product_rows)
    elif select_option_BV == 'b':
        Product_Matrix_Framework.plot(x="Product name",y="Price")
    elif select_option_BV == 'c':
        print(Product_Matrix_Framework.sort_values("Price"))
    elif select_option_BV == 'd':
        Product_Matrix_Framework.to_excel("Products.xlsx")
    elif select_option_BV == 'e':
        print("CY@ exiting...")
        break
```

And I don't know what mistake I did but I can't make it work! I need it for a project for my university but I'm stuck on it right now, I don't know what I did wrong, when I'm writing "a" in console doesn't do anything and if I write any other letter says: "name 'Product_Matrix_Framework' is not defined" please help! Thank you.

Comment: 'Product_Matrix_Framework is not defined' comes up because ```Product_Matrix_Framework``` has not been defined under those if statement branches, it is only defined under the 'a' branch. Try inputting 'a' and then another letter without restarting the program.

Comment: Still doesn't work, this code works for someone else with a different site and different classes, but I can't make it work with my own site

Comment: Well, if its a different site then there's a chance that ```children_element``` might be an empty array, so the for loop under the 'a' branch won't do anything.

Comment: Oh, I understand, well... `productDesc` has two arrays in web code or how is it called, and the first one is empty, can you please tell me how can I select the second one?

Comment: The HTML code looks like this: 

`<p class="productDesc"></p>        /           
<p class="productDesc">Whiting &amp; Davis Crystal Ball Clutch</p>`

with two of productDesc

Answer (score 1):

I think the `elementHTML` isn't necessary.
You just use the `children_element` by searching for css selector.

```
...
driver_BV.get("https://www.qvc.com/handbags-and-luggage/handbags/clutches/_/N-1cknw/c.html?qq=mh")
product_BV=[]
price_BV=[]
Final=[]
children_element=driver_BV.find_elements_by_css_selector(".plContent .galleryItem")
```

It will find 60 items of goods.
After that, the error keeps occurring and I think you need to fix those errors in `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at some documentation sites and the website itself (I'm assuming you want the elements with CSS selector `productDesc`), I think I see what you want to do.

If you want to select an element by its CSS selector, (`productDesc` in this instance is a CSS selector) you should use:

```py
title_elements = child_element.find_elements_by_css_selector("productDesc")
```

Which should return an array containing all the child elements with the CSS selector `productDesc`, and you can then iterate through that array to get the text of each element. Something like:

```py
titles = []
for title_element in title_elements:
    titles.append(title_elements.get_attribute("innerHtml")
```

Looking at the website, each `child_element` may have one or more elements with the `productDesc` CSS selector, so you should store these in an array in case there are more than one. Your code appears to assume that there is only one.

For example:

```py
...
while True:
    select_option_BV = input("Select option:")
    if select_option_BV == 'a':
        for child_element in children_element:
            titles = []
            for title_element in child_element.find_elements_by_css_selector("productDesc"):
                titles.append(title_element.get_attribute("innerText"))

            product_BV.append(titles)  # Product_BV will now be an array containing more arrays
            ...
```

Comment: I tried, but I can't figure it out, can you please help me edit it? I'm a total newbie in programming, so it would really help me.

Comment: @ValiBarta does that help?

Comment: I have posted a second code that kind off works, If I put your code, I have to change the whole code and I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: And it also says that the command with css selector is deprecated.

Comment: If it is always the second text, then you could just do ```title=child_element.find_elements("class name", "productDesc")[1].get_attribute("innerText")```? Notice the use of ```find_elements``` instead of ```find_element```. The command is deprecated but should still work (I think), although it would probably be better to use ```find_elements``` instead, I used the old one because I haven't used selenium in a while so haven't really used the new functions.

Answer (score 0):

@Nathcat

````
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
driver_RA= webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver_RA.get("https://www.qvc.com/handbags-and-luggage/handbags/clutches/_/N-1cknw/c.html?qq=mh")
product_RA=[]
price_RA=[]
elementHTML=driver_RA.find_element("class name", 'plContent')
Final=[]
children_element=elementHTML.find_elements("class name", 'productInfoWrapper')

print('''
      a. Retrieve data
      b. Create the graph
      c. Display the matrix
      d. Save to Excel file
      e. Exit
      ''')

while True:
    select_option_RA = input("Select option:")
    if select_option_RA == 'a':
        for child_element in children_element:
            title=child_element.find_element("class name", 'productDesc').get_attribute('innerText')
            #Trying to print every SECOND string from productDesc (because for some reason every
            #first innerText from productDesc is empty 
            product_RA.append(title)
            titlu=child_element.find_element("class name", 'priceSell')
            price=titlu.get_attribute('innerText')
            price_RA.append(price)
            print ('Products:', product_RA)
            print ('Prices:', price_RA)
            price=price.replace("€","")
            Final.append(price)
            Product_title_series=pd.Series(product_RA)
            Product_price_series=pd.Series(Final)
            product_rows={"Product name":Product_title_series, "Price":Product_price_series}
            Product_Matrix_Framework=pd.DataFrame(product_rows)
    elif select_option_RA == 'b':
        Product_Matrix_Framework.plot(x="Product name",y="Price")
    elif select_option_RA == 'c':
        print(Product_Matrix_Framework.sort_values("Price"))
    elif select_option_RA == 'd':
        Product_Matrix_Framework.to_excel("Products.xlsx")
    elif select_option_RA == 'e':
        print("Exiting beep boop beep.")
        break```

I did this, but I can't get the products, if I run it and type "a", it shows the prices but not the products
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).